# Do I need to shutdown VM at my EXSI before I add EXSI host to my Vcenter?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a few VM in my EXSI, I was thinking should I shut down my VM when adding EXSI to Vcenter?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking if you should shut a populated hypervisor down prior to joining it to vcenter or shutdown existing vcenter hosted guests prior to adding a new vacant node to vcenter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that. That would defeat one of the main purposes of vcenter - elastic online hypervisor clustering. However, when removing a hypervisor node you will have to evacuate it of VMs first.

Comment: Hi Spooler, Thanks for the reply. I was thinking if I required to shutdown the VM prior to add ESXI to Vcenter. Thanks for answering